# Mac File Paths and Python 3.2, making it executable?

Tags: python, macos, osx-yosemite

I'm just doing a test, titled mactest.py

The contents of this file are:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print "I\'m Working."
```

I executed

```
chmod a+x mactest.py
```

So the tutorial suggests I should simply type into the shell:
`~/Work/courses/python>python <filename>.py`

And that will print `I'm Working.`

Clearly, this is not my file path and I don't know how that person's file system is organized, so I can't replicate this. I tried "get info" on the .py I created on my desktop, and used that information to no avail.

Comment: if you type `python` by itself on the command line, does it start the python repl?

Answer (score -1):

The path name you see in the example is not part of what you should type. If you are in the same directory as the file, all you need is

```
python mactest.py
```

As a matter of fact, because you did the `chmod`, this will also work:

```
./mactest.py
```

However, the script seems to contain Python 2 code, so it won't work with Python 3. On recent macOS, out of the box, just `python` should run Python 2; so that's what you should put in the shebang line if you don't change the code.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "I'm Working."
```

The equivalent code in Python 3 would look like

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print("I'm Working.")
```